# Sitecore DateField's DateTime property shows wrong date

Tags: c#, datetime, sitecore

In my Sitecore project I use `DateTime`(Sitecore's type) field as propery of an `Item`. I'm trying to get this value by following code:

```
var dateField = (DateField)item.Fields["Date"];
var itemDate = dateField.DateTime;
```

But `itemDate` contains wrong date.
Let's check `dateField.Value`: it contains correct date in format: yyyymmddThhmmss. You can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

As you can see `DateTime`'s date is September 13, but `Value`'s date is September 14.

What reasons of this problem? How to get correct data from `DateField` as `DateTime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because internally Sitecore stores all the dates in UTC format. If you timezone has big difference with UTC - you are likely to come into that situation. Use **Sitecore.DateUtil** to make Sitecore do "dirty job" for you.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/utc/datetime/datetime_best_practices

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

I have found solution how to get correct data from `DateField` as `DateTime`:

```
var dateField = (DateField)item.Fields["Date"];
var itemDate = Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(dateField.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime` to correctly convert the date. There is also an override `treatLegacyDatesAsUtc` which can help to get the correct UTC time.

I noticed the link in Martins accepted answer was broken, I was unable to post a comment so I have added a working link here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/utc/datetime/datetime_best_practices

Comment: Do you have another link version? This one is broken (again seems like it).