# Time in Sitecore StartDate is not proper

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, sitecore, sitecore8

SiteCore DateTime value for StartDate is displaying proper Date at frontend (view) but not displaying proper time. Like if time selected is 2 p.m. at Sitecore cms, it should display 14:00 but instead it is displaying 17:00.  How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/sitecore-8-servertimezone-my-dates-are-all-wrong/

Sitecore uses UTC times in the database. In your display, you'll need to convert that to your local time zone.

More information here: [Sitecore DateField's DateTime property shows wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537840/sitecore-datefields-datetime-property-shows-wrong-date) and https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/utc/settings_supporting_utc_implementation

Comment: lemme implement

Comment: this link does not work anymore     https://sdn.sitecore.net/doc/api%205.1.1/Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime_overload_2.html

Comment: You shouldn't use links to sdn.sitecore.net for this - use doc.sitecore.net for Sitecore 8+.

Comment: public DateTime serverTime =Sitecore.DateUtil.ToServerTime( ).            How to add this value in  "20170312T190000Z"? I am bothering about time only.

Comment: 20170312T190000Z is a field value I am getting in iso format for 3 p.m. How can i convert 20170413T190000Z into 3 p.m. or 15:00???